# What is the purpose of unannotated arguments in Spring controller handler methods?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Suppose I have a POST handler method:

```
@PostMapping("/group/{id}")
public OutParameters findRealTimeOrder(@RequestParam String anyParam,
                                       @RequestBody String payload,
                                       @PathVariable("id") String groupId,
                                       InParameters parameters) {
    return service.process(parameters);
}
```

All annotations here have descriptive documentation so I know what is their purpose, but I have no idea what is the last parameter for. How it is related to the request?

Comment: `InParameters` to me suggests a Stored Procedure.

Comment: It's just a custom entity from my project like OutParameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from [spring doc:](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-methods)

> If a method argument is not matched to any of the above, by default it
>   is resolved as an @RequestParam if it is a simple type, as determined
>   by BeanUtils#isSimpleProperty, or as an @ModelAttribute otherwise.

Comment: Didn't know about `@ModelAttribute` either, thank you.